# How to run parallel with multiplying increment

Tags: linux, bash, shell, parallel-processing

I know that I can use "parallel" to run multiple instances of whatever script/application in parallel over a variable with a given increment, eg:

```
parallel "echo hello {}" ::: {1..16..2}
```

Output would be:

```
hello 1
hello 3
hello 5
hello 7
hello 9
hello 11
hello 13
hello 15
```

I want to use an increment that multiplies the run variable so that I get an output like this:

```
hello 1
hello 2
hello 4
hello 8
hello 16
```

What should I write in the {1..16..#}?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you need to add `-k` to be assured of your desired output order...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
parallel "echo hello {}" ::: $(awk 'BEGIN {for(i=0; i<=16; i++) printf 2**i" "}')
```

`awk` is used to print out a list of powers of 2 which will then be used by `parallel`.

Alternatively:

```
parallel "echo hello {}" ::: $(printf '%s\n' 2^{0..16} | bc | tr '\n' ' ')
```

This prints out the numbers 1 to 16 as part of the string `x^2`, `printf` ensures each number is on a separate line. `bc` then computes the actual numbers, and `tr` removes the newlines again.

Comment: OP only wants up to 16, so it would be better to use `while(2^i<=16) print 2^i++}'`

Comment: first command gives me: 
`hello awk 
hello BEGIN {for(i=0; i<=16; i++) printf 2**i" "}`
second one works as expected. I'd like to see the awk version working, though...

Comment: Sorry, I missed out the enclosing brackets (command substitution syntax) - try now.

Answer (score 1):

Use {= =} (available in **version 20140822** and later):

```
seq 1 2 16 | parallel echo hello {}
parallel echo hello '{= $_=2*$_ =}' ::: {1..16}
seq 1 16 | parallel echo hello '{= $_=2**$_ =}'
parallel echo hello '{= $_=2**$_ =}'  ::: {1..16}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, for the last three commands, I only get errors from zsh:
`zsh:1: parse error near `}'`

Comment: I get that too, but only if I use version < 20140822. So make sure you are using version > 20140822.

Comment: Oh, sorry - didn't catch that version hint. I just checked and noticed, I'm still on 20130922 - this might be the problem here...